# Is it a good practice to source map-file in css file?

Tags: css, sass

I use a GUI application for compilation where I can choose to Source Map.

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=Site.css.map */
```

Does this affect performance of the website?

Answer (score 2):

Source maps could be useful during development.

When source maps are enabled in the browser the source reference for all styles will change from the css to the Sass.

This improves the ability to debug in the browser,source maps increases the depth of diagnostic capabilities - by allowing the developer to directly access the pre-compiled code.

Click [here](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/using-source-maps-with-sass) for further reading and understanding